# how to fix the Dspace REST API error message

Tags: rest, dspace

I try  to install Dspace 7.4 REST API on a  server machine  running on Debian 11, with the necessary packages: (Java 17.0.6 / Maven 3.8.7 / Postgres 15 / Tomcat9 / Solr 8.11.2)

And it works very well when I access from the browser on: http://10.1.1.38:8080  and: http://10.1.1.38:8080/server

Then I installed dspace UI with the necessary configuration (Node JS 16, YARN and PM2)

And I installed the apache web server to use it as a reverse proxy for Tomcat like this:

<VirtualHost *:80>

```
    ServerName 10.1.1.38

    ProxyRequestsOn

    ProxyPass / http://10.1.1.38:4000/

    ProxyPassReverse / http://10.1.1.38:4000/
```

But the problem is when I launch the site on the browser: http://10.1.1.38:4000 the initial page of the demo site is displayed for a moment and then the error 500 is displayed tell me :

"Le serveur n'est temporairement pas en mesure de répondre à votre demande en raison d'un arrêt dû à une opération de maintenance ou à des problèmes de capacité. Veuillez réessayer plus tard",

I try this command to check the rest API response and I got this message:

"
yarn run v1.22.19
$ ts-node --project ./tsconfig.ts-node.json scripts/test-rest.ts
Building production app config
Overriding app config with /dspace-angular-dspace-7.4/config/config.yml
Overriding app config with /dspace-angular-dspace-7.4/config/config.prod.yml
...Testing connection to REST API at http://10.1.1.38:8080/server/api...

RESPONSE: 404

ERROR: INVALID DSPACE REST API! Response is not valid JSON!
Response returned:
<!doctype html>État HTTP 404 – Non trouvébody {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;} h1, h2, h3, b {                                                                                        color:white;background-color:#525D76;} h1 {font-size:22px;} h2 {font-size:16px;}                                                                                         h3 {font-size:14px;} p {font-size:12px;} a {color:black;} .line {height:1px;bac                                                                                        kground-color:#525D76;border:none;}

## État HTTP 404 – Non                                                                                         trouvé

**Type** Rapport d'état

**message**                                                                                         La ressource demandée [/server/api] n'est pas disponible

**d                                                                                        escription** La ressource demandée n'est pas disponible.

<hr class="line" /                                                                                        >

#### Apache Tomcat/9.0.70 (Debian)

Done in 2.51s.

I try to fix that problem and I didn’t get the solution

Could you help me to solve this problem?

And thanks a lot

Comment: First up, get everything working with Yarn first, and then try getting it working with PM2, and then last, the reverse proxy (with a domain name for your ServerName instead of the IP address). 
To get it working with Yarn, your config.yml (or config.prod.yml or config.dev.yml, whichever you are using) will need to have values that match what is in your backend's local.cfg. 
If it still isn't working, please share the values you have in those 2 files that pertain to "ui" and "rest".